# Guice Assisted : No implementation for java.lang.String annotated with @com.google.inject.assistedinject.Assisted(value=prefix) was bound

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, guice-3

I've done this a million of times, but right now it's not working and I don't know why !

I've my interface that defines the contract of the Writers like :

```java
public interface Writer {
    
    void exit() throws IOException;

    void write(String row) throws IOException;
}
```

Concrete implementation :

```java
import com.google.inject.assistedinject.Assisted;
import javax.inject.Inject;


public class TextFileWriter implements Writer {

    //...
    @Inject
    public TextFileWriter(@Assisted("store") String store, @Assisted("prefix") String prefix, @Assisted Line line, @Assisted LocalDate date) throws IOException {
    //...
    }

    //...
}
```

Now the factory :

```java
public interface WriterFactory {
    
    Writer textWriter(String store, String prefix, Line line, LocalDate date) throws IOException;
}
```

And finally my config :

```java
@Override
protected void configure() {
    install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
            .implement(Writer.class, TextFileWriter.class)
            .build(WriterFactory.class)
    );
}
```

With all of this at the startup it throws an exception that is saying :

> 1. No implementation for java.lang.String annotated with
>    @com.google.inject.assistedinject.Assisted(value=prefix) was bound.
>    while locating java.lang.String annotated with
>    @com.google.inject.assistedinject.Assisted(value=prefix)
>    for the 2nd parameter of daemons.filerecorder.TextFileWriter.(TextFileWriter.java:38)
>    at daemons.filerecorder.WriterFactory.textWriter(WriterFactory.java:1)
>    at
>    com.google.inject.assistedinject.FactoryProvider2.initialize(FactoryProvider2.java:666)
>    at
>    com.google.inject.assistedinject.FactoryModuleBuilder$1.configure(FactoryModuleBuilder.java:335)
>    (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule ->
>    modules.GuiceConfig ->
>    com.google.inject.assistedinject.FactoryModuleBuilder$1)
> 2. No implementation for java.lang.String annotated with
>    @com.google.inject.assistedinject.Assisted(value=store) was bound.
>    while locating java.lang.String annotated with
>    @com.google.inject.assistedinject.Assisted(value=store)
>    for the 1st parameter of daemons.filerecorder.TextFileWriter.(TextFileWriter.java:38)
>    at daemons.filerecorder.WriterFactory.textWriter(WriterFactory.java:1)
>    at
>    com.google.inject.assistedinject.FactoryProvider2.initialize(FactoryProvider2.java:666)
>    at
>    com.google.inject.assistedinject.FactoryModuleBuilder$1.configure(FactoryModuleBuilder.java:335)
>    (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule ->
>    modules.GuiceConfig ->
>    com.google.inject.assistedinject.FactoryModuleBuilder$1)
> 3. A binding to java.lang.String annotated with
>    @com.google.inject.assistedinject.Assisted(value=) was already
>    configured at daemons.filerecorder.WriterFactory.textWriter().   at
>    daemons.filerecorder.WriterFactory.textWriter(WriterFactory.java:1)
>    at
>    com.google.inject.assistedinject.FactoryProvider2.initialize(FactoryProvider2.java:666)
>    at
>    com.google.inject.assistedinject.FactoryModuleBuilder$1.configure(FactoryModuleBuilder.java:335)
>    (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule ->
>    modules.GuiceConfig ->
>    com.google.inject.assistedinject.FactoryModuleBuilder$1)

Any idea to get this work ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Add `@Assisted` to the ambiguous `String`-typed parameters of the interface

You're missing the `@Assisted` parameter on the factory method. So adapt as follow:

```
public interface WriterFactory {
  Writer textWriter(@Assisted("store") String store, @Assisted("prefix") String prefix, Line line, LocalDate date) throws IOException;
}
```

This is explained in the [`FactoryModuleBuilder` javadoc, section "Making parameter types distinct"](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/assistedinject/FactoryModuleBuilder.html). It's mandatory because you have two parameters with the same type, `String`.